# REPLACE INTO Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an odd issue that is my replace into query is not working , I have tried numerous times to see if Ive missed anything but still cannot seem to understand what could be causing my query not to work .

The query is $sqlt4 the last query below I'm having this issue with .

visited is my table name , online is the col I'm indexing "No" is just a string im trying to replace into .

I have a unique index on username and id is AI

[image]

Can somebody please help with this , Thanks.

```
include('..\db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);


//if user session is active 
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){

    //This works fine
    $sqlt2 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_members VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CurrentUser']."','".$time."')");

    // LAST SEEN ONLINE TIME FOR THE USER , This works fine
    $sqlt3 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO visited (username, time, online) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CurrentUser']."',now(), 'No')");

}  // end if

else{
    //if no session active  users logs out

    //NEED TO FIND OUT WHY IT WONT WORK TO REPLACE
    $sqlt4 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO visited (online) VALUES ('Yes')");


}  // end else
```

Comment: Replace into needs to have a unique or primary key constraint. `online` is neither.

Comment: ^^^ that. And if you don't have a current username, you probably don't know either which row you need to update so I don't see how you can run any kind of update query there.

Comment: @jeroen I do have the username set , You are looking a snippet of code .

Comment: @JonStirling A primary Key and a Unique Index are both set of the col online makes no difference . Still problem remains

Comment: Then you can use the same query you are using for `$sqlt3` with different values. However, your last statement doesn't make any sense, the `online` values are obviously not unique and you can only have one primary key.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks , You were right . Perfect ! I need the Update Where Statement